# C++ invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char'

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm new to Arduino and C++. I wanted to make a program which will read input from a serial port. However there seem to be some problems when I try to compile it.

The error message that I am receiving is:

> invalid conversion from `const char*` to `char`

Here is my code:

```
#define nombreBouteille 10
#define nombreCocktail 8

String cocktail[nombreCocktail][nombreBouteille][2]; 
String bouteille[nombreBouteille];
int serialValue;


void loop() {

  if (Serial.available() > 0) 
    int serialValue = Serial.read();
  if (serialValue == '1') {
     readBouteille();
     readCocktail();
  }
}


//Read and set the bottles content
void readBouteille() {

  for( int i = 0; i < nombreBouteille; i++) {
  bouteille[i] = Serial.readStringUntil(" ");
   }
} 


//Read the cocktail
void readCocktail() {

  for( int i = 0; i < nombreCocktail; i++) {
    for ( int j = 0; j < nombreBouteille; j++) {
      cocktail[i][j][0] = Serial.readStringUntil(" ");
      cocktail[i][j][1] = Serial.parseInt();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 5):

[readStringUntil](https://www.processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/Serial_readStringUntil_.html) takes a single `char` parameter to specify a delimiter, not a C string (`const char *`). So change:

```
bouteille[i] = Serial.readStringUntil(" "); // wrong: " " is a `const char *`
```

to:

```
bouteille[i] = Serial.readStringUntil(' '); // right: ' ' is a `char`
```

and similarly for the other call to `readStringUntil`.

Comment: Minor nitpick, " " is a `const char *`

Comment: @RobK: thanks - fixed !

Comment: @RobK No, it's `const char[2]`.

Comment: True, but in this instance as a function argument it decays to `const char *` .